# Firebase Authorization

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Swift and Firebase. I have created several labels that I want to unhide in my account creation view controller, like password must be at least 6 characters in length, email is not valid and so forth. I have no idea how to create the if, else statements for that, or if Firebase already has something built in. Again this is just for Swift, I know there's info for Android but I don't really understand it.

This is currently my code.

```
@IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let email = emailField.text, !email.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    guard let pwd = confirmPass.text, !pwd.isEmpty, confirmPass.text == PassField.text else {
        passMatch.isHidden = false
        return
    }

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: pwd, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.emailTaken.isHidden = false
            self.emailTaken.text = FirebaseAuthException().getReason()
        } else {
            if let user = user {
                let userData = ["provider": user.providerID]
                self.completeSignIn(id: user.uid, userData: userData)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I got rid of self.emailTaken.text = FirebaseAuthException().getReason() because it kept giving me errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out a lot of the error handling for this. If anybody is interested, and ever encounters the same problem, just follow this. I'm sure there's a better way with snapshots but this accomplishes the problem at its most basic.

```
@IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender: Any) {


    guard let email = emailField.text, !email.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    guard let pwd = confirmPass.text, !pwd.isEmpty, confirmPass.text == PassField.text else {
        passMatch.isHidden = false
        return
    }

    passMatch.isHidden = true

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: pwd, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            if let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: (error?._code)!) {
                switch errorCode {
                case .errorCodeNetworkError:
                    print("A network error occurred")
                case .errorCodeInvalidEmail:
                    self.emailTaken.isHidden = false
                case .errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse:
                    self.emailTaken.isHidden = false
                case .errorCodeWeakPassword:
                    self.passRule.isHidden = false
                default:
                    print("Create User Error: \(error)")
                    }
            }
        } else {
            if let user = user {
                let userData = ["provider": user.providerID]
                self.completeSignIn(id: user.uid, userData: userData)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase handles almost everything for you, here is a list of errors that they provide and you can use:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors#method_specific_error_codes

Or you can just show the `NSLocalizedDescription` like here:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error as? NSError{
            if let errorMessage = error.userInfo["NSLocalizedDescription"] as? String {
                //Show Alert with message provided in 'errorMessage'
            } else {
                //Show General Alert
            }
        } else if let user = user {
            //Logged in
        } else {
           // Unknow State
    }
```